# How do I get information about why a background download is failing?

Tags: windows-runtime, download

In WinRT, I am trying to spawn a background download and seem to be hitting my head against the wall.  I have the following code:

```
                var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
                var operation = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(rendition.Url), resultingFile);

                var downloadTask = operation.StartAsync().AsTask(new Progress<DownloadOperation>(ProgressHandler));
```

Stepping through the code one at a time, when I call `CreateDownload()` the resulting `operation.Progres..Status` is `Idle`, which is logical as I haven't started it yet.

However, if I take one step more so the `StartAsync()` runs, `operation.Progress.Status` now equals `Error`.  My progress handler is never called.

Is there any way to get more detailed information about what the error is?  I can't find anything to tell me what's wrong with the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first I can't see that you have assigned your

```
resultingFile
```

I use

```
StorageFile file = /* Instantiate */;
```

I'm creating a multiple tasks, because of the need to download many files.

Then I do it like this, referring to your code now

```
 //List to hold my tasks
 List<Task> dloadTasks = new List<Task>();

 //SET callback
 Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(DownloadProgress);
 //YOUR CODE!
 var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
 var operation = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(rendition.Url),   resultingFile);

 //Your code modified a bit
 var yourResult = await operation.StartAsync().AsTask(progressCallback);


 //This is where my way changes from your way
 Task downloadCompletionTask = HandleDownloadAsync(operation , true);

 //Add to list with tasks
 dloadTasks.Add(downloadCompletionTask);

 //Then i Await them
 await Task.WhenAll(downloadCompletionTasks);
```

Comment: My assignment of resultingFile is fine, as it's actually creating the file on the system via folder.CreateFileAsync

Comment: @KallDrexx I know but you can't be sure :) How about the rest?

Comment: I can't really comment on the rest, as the only difference between your code and mine is you have some HandleDownloadAsync method that you are using to start the download, and without being able to see what you are doing in there that's different than just calling StartAsync it's hard for me to say.

Comment: @KallDrexx try this var downloadTask = await operation.StartAsync().AsTask(new Progress<DownloadOperation>(ProgressHandler));

Comment: @KallDrexx Have you tried setting the progressHanlder outside, it's a callback.. like this
Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>() and then

var downloadTask = operation.StartAsync().AsTask(progressCallback);

Comment: Actually, looking at your comment it turns out the Error is coming through as an exception, and since I"m not awaiting it's never bubbling up.  doing `await operation.StartAsync();` throws a file not found exception, so at least I have something to go on now.